# How to reframe the dataframe based on column and row values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
data = {
    'Title': ['001C', '001C', '004C', '001C', '004C', '004C', '007C', '010C'],
    'Items': ['A', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'K', 'L', 'M']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

df

```
    Title   Items
0   001C    A
1   001C    B
2   004C    D
3   001C    A
4   004C    A
5   004C    K
6   007C    L
7   010C    M
```

I want to get the `Items` under each `Title` without any redundancy. The expected output is

```
    001C    004C    007C    010C
0   A       D       L       M
1   B       A                
2           K
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `drop_duplicates`, `assign` a helper column with increasing indexes per Item per group, and `pivot`:

```
(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Title', 'Items'])
   .assign(index=df.groupby('Title').cumcount())
   .pivot(index='index', columns='Title', values='Items')
   .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
  #.fillna('') # uncomment if you want empty strings in place of NaNs 
)
```

output:

```
      001C 004C 007C 010C                 
0        A    D    L    M
1        B    A  NaN  NaN
2      NaN    K  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Yes.  And if the NaNs bother the OP, they can use `fillna`.

Comment: `df.columns.name, df.index.name = None, None` if you want to match OP's desired output exactly.

Comment: @ddejohn yes, you're right, I updated the post (using `rename_axis`)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) + [`.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html).  Then, relocate the non-NaN values of each column to the top by [`.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html), as follows:

```
(df.drop_duplicates()
   .pivot(columns='Title', values='Items')
   .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

**Result:**

```
  001C 004C 007C 010C
0    A    D    L    M
1    B    A  NaN  NaN
2  NaN    K  NaN  NaN
```